# Styling an Embedded LWC on Flow screen

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, css

Is it possible to match the width of the standard screen elements that flow provides out of the box (like "Date" & "Type")? My custom LWC (Products) seems to be taking up 100% of the real estate of the flow screen.

To compare I also dragged the standard lookup screen element from Salesforce and even that one seems to take up the entire space.

[image]

Comment: As an option, that workaround could have helped https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/410840/70921

Answer (score 0):

The Flow Screen inputs have a max-width of 700px. You could apply this same max-width to your input, but keep in mind that this is something that salesforce doesn't guarantee to not change.

myComponent.html

```
<div style="my-class">
 <!-- content -->
</div
```

myComponent.css

```
.my-class{
 max-width : 700px;
}
```