# Style input elements (width) inside Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, css, style, screen-flow

Is it possible to somehow style elements inside the screen flow?
I have 4 elements, the first 2 are flow standard Text elements. The third one is the standard lookup field and the last one is my custom LWC component. Seems like the lookup is getting 100% width by default, like all the other elements, but still is much bigger than the rest of them. I can make custom LWC to be the same width, but the custom text is always much smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Especially having in mind that you cannot embed flow in LWC (yet) so you cannot even try to 'hack' it somehow (at least using LWC, either way it is not good idea to do so)
I've checked the difference between normal inputs and lookups and apparent input have class called `flowruntime-input`which limits their width to 700 px. Lookup does not have something like that implemented.

To be honest I believe it is a bug actually. If you have the possibility try to contact Salesforce Support.

Good news is that if you place your flow with space smaller than 700px there won't be any difference... (yeat staying positive here :))

Comment: Thanks for replying, I found out same things and that is really strange behavior. There is no way I can hack it, to override those styling classes...

Comment: I do not recommend it, but you can try my old idea about 'overriding' standard styles. Embed your flow in aura component. Find name of the class which is used to style flow lookup. Add this class in css file of the aura component with !important max-width: 700px property. I was changing in a similar way standard modals, maybe it will work also on flow (didnt try it though)

Answer (score 0):

To make the lookup smaller you could use Section. Add several columns there and put the field in the middle. Other columns remain empty. Then adjust the width of the columns the way you need.
[image]